# Cannot assign value to variable =The variable shape (1, 1, 256, 512), and the assigned value shape (512, 128, 1, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I have an issue with my resnet model I try using it to create and train custom face recognition model as shown below but I get an error can I get help in it I will put both the code and the error

```
def resnet50tl(input_shape, outclass, sigma='sigmoid'):
    
    base_model = None
    base_model = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
    base_model.load_weights(resnet50weight)
    
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    
    top_model = Sequential()
    top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
    for i in range(2):
        top_model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
        top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    top_model.add(Dense(outclass, activation=sigma))

   
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=top_model(base_model.output))
    if resnet50weight is not None:
        # Load the weights with by_name=True, and using specific weight names
        model.load_weights(resnet50weight, by_name=True,
                           skip_mismatch=True, reshape=True)

    return model
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)  # Change this to your input image shape
numclasses = 6 
model = resnet50tl(input_shape, numclasses, 'softmax')
lr = 1e-5
decay = 1e-7 #0.0
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=lr, decay=decay)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the error is as follows :

```
File "c:\Users\mahmo\Downloads\test\VGG model.py", line 109, in <module>
        model = resnet50tl(input_shape, numclasses, 'softmax')
      File "c:\Users\mahmo\Downloads\test\VGG model.py", line 87, in resnet50tl
        base_model.load_weights(resnet50weight)
      File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
      File "C:\Users\mahmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 4361, in _assign_value_to_variable
        variable.assign(value)
    ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable ' conv3_block1_0_conv/kernel:0': Shape mismatch.The variable shape (1, 1, 256, 512), and the assigned value shape (512, 128, 1, 1) are incompatible
```

I was trying to follow this code and test it : https://www.kaggle.com/code/iljoong/celebrity-face-classification-using-keras/notebook

Answer (score -1):

The error message says that there is a shape mismatch when the pre-trained weights are being loaded into the base_model. The shape of the weight tensor being loaded doesn't match the shape of the corresponding tensor in the model.

The `ValueError` is complaining about a layer named `'conv3_block1_0_conv'`, where the variable shape is (1, 1, 256, 512), but the shape of the weights being loaded is (512, 128, 1, 1).

This discrepancy can occur if the architecture of the model you've created doesn't match the architecture of the model from which the weights were originally saved.

The line of code where the error occurs is:

```
base_model.load_weights(resnet50weight)
```

Here, `resnet50weight` should be the path to the weights of a trained `ResNet50` model. However, it seems like the weights you are trying to load do not correspond to the structure of the `ResNet50` model you have defined.

Here are some possible solutions:

Ensure that `resnet50weight` is the correct path to the weights of a `ResNet50` model.

Make sure that the weights file is not corrupt or incomplete.

If you're using a modified version of `ResNet50`, ensure that the weights you're trying to load correspond to that specific architecture.

If you are not sure about the architecture of the model for which the weights were saved, you might want to train the model from scratch or use weights that you are certain match the model architecture.

It's also worth noting that in your code, you are loading weights twice: once in the `ResNet50` constructor and once more with load_weights. If you are using pre-trained weights from `'imagenet'`, you should only need to specify `weights='imagenet'` in the `ResNet50` constructor. Loading weights again may be causing your issue, especially if `resnet50weight` is not a path to weights corresponding to a `ResNet50` model.

*** Update ***

Looking at the Kaggle notebook you linked, the author uses a different approach. He is using the VGGFace model with the ResNet50 architecture as the base model. VGGFace is a model trained for face recognition. He doesn't load the weights for the ResNet50 model; instead, he uses the weights of the VGGFace model.

Here is the function from the Kaggle notebook:

```
def resnet50_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    base_model = VGGFace(
        model='resnet50', 
        include_top=False, 
        input_shape=input_shape, 
        pooling='avg'
    )  # pooling: None, avg or max
    
    # Freeze the layers
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False 

    x = base_model.output
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    
    # Create model
    model = Model(base_model.input, output)
    
    return model
```

When you create a pre-trained model in `Keras`, you have the option to load the weights that were learned during the training of that model on a specific dataset.

In your case, you're using the `ResNet50` model from `keras.applications`, which is pre-trained on the `ImageNet` dataset. When you create an instance of this model using `ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)`, you're already loading the weights that were learned when the model was trained on `ImageNet`.

Later in your `resnet50tl` function, you're trying to load the weights again using `base_model.load_weights(resnet50weight)`. This is unnecessary because the weights have already been loaded when you created the model.

If `resnet50weight` is the path to a file containing weights that you've trained on a different dataset and want to use instead of the `ImageNet` weights, you should create the base model with `weights=None`, and then load your weights. Here is how you would do that:

```
base_model = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
base_model.load_weights(resnet50weight)
```

In this case, `resnet50weight` should be the path to the weights file you want to load.

In your case, if you want to use the `VGGFace model`, you need to install the `keras-vggface` library, which is not included in standard `Keras`. You can install it using the following command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface.git
```

Then you can import it in your script:

```
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
```

And replace `keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50` with `VGGFace(model='resnet50')` in your `resnet50tl` function.

Comment: didnt fix it for me i tried it before